# Змейка массив php

Tags: массивы, php

Написать программу, в которой прямоугольный массив будет заполняться последовательными целыми числами змейкой

```
<?PHP  
function zmeika($n, $m)  
{  
  $z=array();  
  $k=0;  
  for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)  
  {  
    for ($j=0; $j<$m; $j++)  
    {  
      if ($i%2 == 0)  
      {  
        $z[$i][$j]=$k++;  
      }  
      else  
      {  
        $z[$i][$m-$j-1]=$k++;  
      }  
    }

  }  
  return $z;  
}

$a=zmeika(4, 3);  
echo '<PRE>';  
print_r ($a);  
echo '</PRE>';  
?>
```

Выдаёт вот что:

```
Array  
(  
    [0] => Array  
        (  
            [0] => 0  
            [1] => 1  
            [2] => 2  
        )

    [1] => Array  
        (  
            [2] => 3  
            [1] => 4  
            [0] => 5  
        )

    [2] => Array  
        (  
            [0] => 6  
            [1] => 7  
            [2] => 8  
        )

    [3] => Array  
        (  
            [2] => 9  
            [1] => 10  
            [0] => 11  
        )

)
```

Должен:

```
1,2,3,  
6,5,4,  
7,8,9,  
12,11,10,
```

Answer (score 1):

$a у тебя массив. `print_r($a)` выводит массив. Преобразуй массив в строку с помощью [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php), или сделай обход массива с помощью [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php) или [`array_reduce()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

Comment: каким образом, если не секрет?